# Generate two different SP metadata using Spring Security SAML´

Tags: spring-saml

We need to configure two different IdPs. So far so good, but the problem is that we need to configure forceAuthN for one of the IdPs. Another thing is that one IdP is using HTTP-Artifact for bindingsSSO, while the other is using HTTP-POST. Therefore it seems that we need two different SP metadata.

What is the best approach? I guess it's not a problem if we write the metadata ourselves, but we want Spring Security SAML to generate these.

We tried to configure two different metadataGeneratorFilters by extending the MetadataGeneratorFilter class. The problem now is that only metadata for one of the SPs are built, and the reason is simply the following line in the processMetadataInitialization method:

```
if (manager.getHostedSPName() == null) { ...
```

The MetadataManager class can, as far as I know, only hold one hostedSPName, not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need separate metadata in order to control selection of bindings or `forceAuthN`. These settings are configured in the `AuthnRequest` sent to IDP. Just make sure that your SP metadata contains both HTTP-Artifact and HTTP-POST endpoints (which it does by default).

The `AuthnRequest` settings are configured using instances of `WebSSOProfileOptions`. Extend class `SAMLEntryPoint`, override method `getProfileOptions` and return correctly configured `WebSSOProfileOptions` depending on the IDP you are connecting to and the requirements you have. Details are in the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-sso-process-sp-init).

The `forceAuthN` in `AuthnRequest` is configured using property `forceAuthn`. You can select which binding (artifacts vs. post) should IDP use to deliver the SAML message back to SP with property `assertionConsumerIndex`.

You cannot use automatic MetadataGenerator for generating of two different sets of metadata in one instance. In order to do so you can use [pre-configured metadata](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-sp-import) - but I don't think it's needed in your case.